# I have got some error when I install Laravel spark like this

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

PS C:\Win10\tests\spark-installer> cd .\sparkprojectname\
PS C:\Win10\tests\spark-installer\sparkprojectname> php artisan migrate

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'announcements' alrea
  dy exists (SQL: create table `announcements` (`id` varchar(255) not null, `user_id`
  int not null, `body` text not null, `action_text` varchar(255) null, `action_url` te
  xt null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character
   set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists:
>   1050 Table 'announcements' already exists

Answer (score 0):

The table `announcements` already exists in the Database. And hence when you run the migrate command then it triggers the error. If it is necessary to migrate, then delete the table from database.